# Can weighted PageRank values converge to same values regardless of weights?

Tags: graph-algorithm, networkx, pagerank

I recently did a project where I computed the PageRank (and HITS and various centrality scores) for a network with about 500k nodes and 1.2 million edges. I calculated the PageRank scores using the Networkx python package, then tested them with a linear regression against a reasonably reliable external data source. The unweighted scores correlated closely with the external data, but I was confused to find that the weighted PageRank scores all came out the same values (with high precision floats) regardless of how I weighted the edges in the graph, and they didn't correlate at all with the external data. I'm trying to figure out whether I had some error in my code in adding the edges that I didn't notice or whether PageRank might actually converge to the same values regardless of edge weights after a sufficient number of iterations, as I gather it does regardless of starting PageRank values.

Is it possible my edges were indeed weighted differently each run but PageRank produced the same values? Or is something screwed up with my network edges?

Thank you.

**Edit:** Other PageRank questions seem to explain that all out-going weights have to be normalized, which I definitely didn't do. My weights we're all integers, like 4, 10, 15, etc. Could this be the problem?

Comment: You don't have to normalize the weights.

Comment: Can you post a small example showing where you think the answer is wrong?  Otherwise we probably can't help you more.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is it?

The default calling arguments for the networkx.pagerank() function specify that the algorithm should use the 'weight' attribute.
If you have a 'weight' attribute on the edges but want to ignore it chose weight=None.  e.g.

```
In [1]: import networkx as nx

In [2]: G = nx.DiGraph()

In [3]: G.add_edge(1,2,weight=7.0)

In [4]: G.add_edge(1,3,weight=70.0)

In [5]: nx.pagerank(G)
Out[5]: {1: 0.259740259292235, 2: 0.27981109766708, 3: 0.460448643040685}

In [6]: nx.pagerank(G,weight=None)
Out[6]: {1: 0.259740259292235, 2: 0.3701298703538825, 3: 0.3701298703538825}

In [7]: nx.pagerank(G,weight='weight')
Out[7]: {1: 0.259740259292235, 2: 0.27981109766708, 3: 0.460448643040685}
```

Comment: Hmm, I definitely didn't call pagerank with weight=None, so this probably wasn't it. Thank you though!